# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Cross Validated's [3rd moderator election](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Glen_b] [image: Scortchi]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5714987150475264/0).

Comment: Welcome on board!

Comment: Congratulations to both of you!

Comment: Congratulations, Glen and Scortchi.  And grateful thanks to all who participated in the election.  Please continue to contribute to our site and make your voices and concerns heard.  We can continue as a strong community only through the help and ideas of everyone.  (And thanks to you also, Jon Ericson, for posting the election results so expeditiously.)

Comment: Congratulations! I'm sure you'll do this hard job just as great as the others did so far.

Comment: @whuber: No problem. The last three or so elections I've dropped the ball. So this time I used my calendar to remind me. :-)

Comment: Congrats you two! Well deserved and fantastic new mods! :)

Comment: Congratulations Glen_b, Scortchi; two fine additions to our dedicated team of Mods!

Comment: Congratulations! I am sure you will be great additions to the group.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Still trying to figure everything out. Getting there, if a bit slowly.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do my best.

Comment: Congratulations @Glen_b and Scortchi, and thank you for your service!

Comment: I really appreciate the excellent service and insights that both of you have provided to date.  Thanks for taking on these important community roles.

Comment: Congratulations Glen_b and Scortchi !!

Comment: Excellent outcome and congratulations!

Comment: Hell yeah dude!